# How to map data comming from javascript to dto class if it has nested class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

ContactDetail.java

In this, I have a list of phNos

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ContactDetail {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private MultipartFile image;

    private List<PhoneNumber> phNos;

}
```

PhoneNumber.java

In this, I have added a parameterized constructor

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PhoneNumber {
    private Integer id;
    private String phNo;

    public PhoneNumber(String phNo) {
        super();
        this.phNo = phNo;
    }
}
```

DemoRestController.java

In this, want to map using @ModelAttribute

```
@PostMapping("/save/c")
    public void saveContact(@ModelAttribute ContactDetail contactDetail) {
    System.out.println(contactDetail);
}
```

Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
                
    let fdata = new FormData();
    fdata.append("name", "hello");
    fdata.append("image", $("#contactimage")[0].files[0]);
    fdata.append("phNos", [{id:1,phNo:"12345"}]);
    fetch("/save/c", {
        body: fdata,
        method: "post"
    }).then((response) => {
        //Somecode  
    });
});
```

When I am try to send code with this

```
fdata.append("phNos", [{id:1,phNo:"12345"}]);
```

Getting output like this

```
ContactDetail(id=null, name=hello, phNos=[PhoneNumber(id=null, phNo=[object Object])])
```

But when sending data like

```
fdata.append("phNos", "12345");
```

Getting Output like

```
ContactDetail(id=null, name=hello, phNos=[PhoneNumber(id=null, phNo=12345)])
```

**Need Data to be like**

```
ContactDetail(id=null, name=hello, phNos=[PhoneNumber(id=1, phNo=12345)])
```

If I remove that parameterized constructor from PhoneNumber class
then this error occurred

```
Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors<EOL>Field error in object 'contactDetail' on field 'phNos': rejected value [[object Object]]; codes [typeMismatch.contactDetail.phNos,typeMismatch.phNos,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [contactDetail.phNos,phNos]; arguments []; default message [phNos]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'phNos'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.akn.PhoneNumber' for property 'phNos[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

Is there any way it can be done, Reason behind using formdata is to send image data also i.e., multipart/data

I have tried creating different constructors it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with how you're sending the `phNos` data in the `FormData` object. When you send `fdata.append("phNos", [{id:1,phNo:"12345"}])`, Spring is interpreting that as a single `PhoneNumber` object with the properties `id` and `phNo` set to the string "[object Object]".
Instead you can try converting the data in javascript before appending it to the FormData object.
You can use JSON.stringify() to convert the data to a string format before appending it to the FormData object.

```
fdata.append("phNos", JSON.stringify([{id:1,phNo:"12345"}]));
```

Also, update the content type header when sending the request.

```
    fetch("/save/c", {
    body: fdata,
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then((response) => {
    //Somecode  
});
```

This way you don't need to deserialize it on the server side and Spring will map the data to your ContactDetail class automatically.

Also, you can remove the parameterized constructor from PhoneNumber class and use `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` to deserialize it.

Comment: I have changed a Question little bit, I have to send image data as well, what changes are required